# Limit of call requests using Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm currently working with Azure AD B2C authentication and I need to accomplish some tasks on users using the Azure AD Graph API (NOT MS Graph, as stated here: [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)).
I know there are some throttling policies that may occur using the Azure AD Graph API, but I didn't found the true rate limit that I have to respect to avoid this side-effect. 


Do you know the average number of request I can made to the endpoint to avoid this error? Is the limit evaluated per-application registered (Azure registered applications) or per-tenant?


Do you know what is a typical amount of second I must attend before a retry when throttling policies are applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the limits of the Azure Graph APIs is not documented anywhere.

But you can check and handle the possibility of throttling from this [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling)

Comment: That's the same answer the MS Support Team give me today. I was unlucky to find some more detailed info about limits.

Answer (score 1):

For the throttling guidance for Azure AD Graph API, see:

1. [Throttling guidance | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-throttling)
2. [Azure AD Graph API Throttling Guidance](http://www.deployazure.com/security/identity/azure-ad/azure-ad-graph-api-throttling-guidance/)

See the second article for information about limits for reads by a single application and/or from a single IP address:

*"There is an entry point that controls traffic into the Graph API service. From working with the product support  there is a limit of 1000 requests per second to this entry point from a single source IP. Secondly, there is also a separate ApplicationID+TenantID limit in place and this is 120 requests per second. If you require more than this, then you should look to spread the requests across multiple source IPs and applications."*

Comment: The second link you added ("Auzre AD Graph API Throttling Guidance") seems to be missing now.